# what is the font used in x11 terminal

Tags: fonts

I install FontForge on Mac and launch it, from its menu launch Terminal. The Terminal is using a font I very like. It's very crisp and clear, though the screenshot looks not that much. I guess the font file could be right in FontForge.app folder, but I am stupid which file it is and how to use it in Mac.

Can anybody tell me where can I download the font file, or which file in FontForge.app is and how to convert Mac version?  Thanks.

[image: what's the font]

Comment: FontForge is open source. Just head over to [their repo](https://github.com/fontforge/fontforge) and find out?

Answer (score 0):

This is not FontForge, you are looking at XTerm that is bundled with X11.

You can find out what font your XTerm is using with the following command:

```
appres XTerm xterm | grep font5
```

In my case it shows that I am using the font 9x15, which can be found here:
http://underpop.online.fr/l/linux-console-fonts-for-windows-in-ttf-and-fon/

Comment: Thanks a lot. The link provides a TTF file and .FON files. The TTF file can work on Mac but the character are different from those in .FON files. While .FON files looks good but cannot work on Mac. Meamwhile, I find [zevv-peep](http://zevv.nl/play/code/zevv-peep/), which is very close to what I want, but it also does not provides Mac version. I tried with FontForge converting from .bdf to .ttf, but generated font is not recognized. Can you please help? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah. That's just the difference between bitmap and vector fonts. You should probably look for a .dfont copy you like. A quick google search for 9x15 dfont turns up several results. You'll also need to turn off anti aliasing to get that true terminal look.